# C# generic for running function in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics

I have a few generic function for running methods in background threads. Are there any dangers here outside of normal thread sync issues?

```
    public static void ThreadRunReturn<TReturn, TArgument>(Func<TArgument, TReturn> func, TArgument arg, bool background = true)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(unused => func(arg));
        th.IsBackground = background;
        th.Start(th);
    }
    public static void ThreadRunReturn<TReturn, TArgument1, TArgument2>(Func<TArgument1, TArgument2, TReturn> func, TArgument1 arg1, TArgument2 arg2, bool background = true)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(unused => func(arg1, arg2));
        th.IsBackground = background;
        th.Start(th);
    }

    public static void ThreadRun<TArgument>(Action<TArgument> action, TArgument arg, bool background = true)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(unused => action(arg));
        th.IsBackground = background;
        th.Start(th);
    }
    public static void ThreadRun<TArgument1, TArgument2>(Action<TArgument1, TArgument2> action, TArgument1 arg1, TArgument2 arg2, bool background = true)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(unused => action(arg1, arg2));
        th.IsBackground = background;
        th.Start(th);
    }
```

Comment: Does everything need to be public?

Comment: Isn't using TPL easier? `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: @L.B I'll look into Task.Factory.StartNew, but a quick glance doesnt seem to be as simple. I want to be able to do the following: MyClass.ThreadRunReturn(RunSShCommand, "reboot");

Comment: @user511670 `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>RunSShCommand("reboot"));`

Comment: @KingCronus The class only contains public static helper functions. The aim is to reduce certain common tasks to a static function call that is can be used across different projects by referencing this library.

Comment: @L.B As a c/c++ programmer i'm a bit new to lambda expressions, that prob would be the preferred way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

background threads do not keep the application alive. if you have long running background processes running and your application terminates, it will not wait for those background threads to complete - it will kill them. just something to keep in mind.